# DialogInterface with a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

My problem is that I am trying to open up a dialogInterface with a `ListView` that has a row with 1 `TextView` and a `CheckBox`. The problem I have is that when the checkBox is clicked, lets say on item 2, item 6 will also be checked, and item 10, and item 14, and all the way when all I want is item 2 to be picked.

What I have tried:

```
 //setup a list adapter and then set that on the list
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(PendingFriendsActivity.this, R.layout.activity_contact_list_item, R.id.contactNameTextView, ContactList);
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(PendingFriendsActivity.this);
DialogInterface.OnClickListener buttonClicked;
buttonClicked = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                for(int i = 0; i < sendContactList.size();i++)
                {
                    String phone, name;
                    name = sendContactList.get(i).get(0);
                    phone = sendContactList.get(i).get(1);
                    sendSMS(phone);
                }
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    }
};
builderSingle.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)view.getParent();
        ArrayList<String> contact = new ArrayList<String>();
        final CheckBox contactCheckBox = (CheckBox) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id.sendCheckBox);
        TextView contactTextView = (TextView) vwParentRow.findViewById(R.id.contactNameTextView);
        Toast.makeText(PendingFriendsActivity.this, contactTextView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(contactCheckBox.isChecked())
        {
            contact.add(fullContacts.get(i).get(0));
            contact.add(fullContacts.get(i).get(1));
            sendContactList.add(contact);
        } else {
            sendContactList.remove(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});

builderSingle.setCancelable(false);
builderSingle.setTitle("Friend Invite");
builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel", buttonClicked);
builderSingle.setPositiveButton("Send Invites", buttonClicked);
builderSingle.setAdapter(listAdapter, buttonClicked);
builderSingle.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                // make a list to hold state of every color
                for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                    ColorVO colorVO = new ColorVO();
                    colorVO.setName(colors[i]);
                    colorVO.setSelected(checkedColors[i]);
                    colorList.add(colorVO);
                }

                // Do something here to pass only arraylist on this both arrays ('colors' & 'checkedColors')
                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colors, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        // set state to vo in list
                        colorList.get(which).setSelected(isChecked);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                colorList.get(which).getName() + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                builder.setCancelable(false);

                builder.setTitle("Your preferred colors?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        txtSelected.setText("Your preferred colors..... \n");

                        // save state of selected vos
                        ArrayList<ColorVO> selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < colorList.size(); i++) {
                            ColorVO colorVO = colorList.get(i);
                            colors[i] = colorVO.getName();
                            checkedColors[i] = colorVO.isSelected();
                            if (colorVO.isSelected()) {
                                selectedList.add(colorVO);
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedList.size(); i++) {
                            // if element is last then not attach comma or attach it
                            if (i != selectedList.size() - 1)
                                txtSelected.setText(txtSelected.getText() + selectedList.get(i).getName() + " ,");
                            else
                                txtSelected.setText(txtSelected.getText() + selectedList.get(i).getName());
                        }
                        colorList.clear();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // make sure to clear list that duplication dont formed here
                        colorList.clear();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // make sure to clear list that duplication dont formed here
                        colorList.clear();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

Hope this can help.!